# Azure B2C Logout in Blazor

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-b2c

I've build a Blazor server app and I'm using the Azure b2c which I build using the wizard.

I don't have a login page and I only use the Google as oauth provider. I just have the default blanket redirect which is fine for me.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

One issue is that I'm facing is that when I'm opening the app it doesn't prompt me asking which account I want to use. I know I'm already signed into my google account as whole but when opening my app I would like the app to prompt for "choosing the account". When I run the same userflow on the azure portal it does prompt me. The same just doesn't happen for my app. How can I make sure that the app always asks to select the account? I read some articles which said to add "prompt" keyword but I don't know where to add that as I'm not calling any custom url.

[image]

[image]

Another issue I'm facing is that the log-out doesn't work as expected. In my app logout sequence is same as the default which redirects user to MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn link.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Once I click the logout button; I does something and then redirects me to this page.

[image]

However once I click the back button, the app opens as normal with the user still signed in. I expected the app to prompt for login at-least this time.

Can you please help me with the right approach for the implementing this. I prefer to avoid advance things like custom user flows. Perhaps some settings in appsettings.json can do the trick?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide the start up class configuration

Answer (score 1):

For the logout to work properly ,In the Redirect URIs section in portal, setredirect URIs.

**Example:**

redirectUri :  `https://localhost:44365/signin-oidc`

In the Logout URL section,  `https://localhost:44365/signout-oidc`  or :  `https://localhost:44365/signin-oidc`

Please check [Configure session behavior - Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#secure-your-logout-redirect)

[image]

In appsetting.json set `"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"` and set a userflow SignedOutCallbackPath

**appsettings.json:**

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://xx.b2clogin.com/XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "Instance": "https://XXXXXX.b2clogin.com",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
    "ClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
   "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
   "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_EditProfile",
    
  },
  "API": {
    "BaseUrl": "",
    "Scopes": "https://XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/ xxx/<scope>"
  },
```

In **startup.cs:**

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = context =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

Or
```

set the prompt value to login or select_account using     OnRedirectToIdentityProvider when OIDC authentication handler is registered

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
   
                .....
  services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("prompt", out string prompt))
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = prompt;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    
    ...
    }
```

[image]

When I logged in

[image]

Selected logout which redirects to signout path  which redirects to  ***`post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44365%2Fsignout-callback-oidc&state=`***

[image]

Then if I clicked back , then I cant access other areas without  login

[image]

**Reference :** [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/blob/main/WebApp-OIDC/B2C/blazorserver-B2C/appsettings.json](https://ms-identity-blazor-server/appsettings.json%20at%20main%20%C2%B7%20Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server%20%C2%B7%20GitHub)